# the isolated hostname is not displaying in the FILE adapter handlers list

Tags: adapter, handler, biztalk, hostname, biztalk-2016

the isolated hostname is not displaying in the FILE adapter handlers list
when I try to add a new send\receive handler to an isolated host I cant see the isolated hostname in the FILE adapter options.
any suggestions about what shall I do?

Comment: Did my below answer help?

Answer (score 1):

The Isolated Host instances should only be used for **Receive Locations** that run in **IIS**. So the fact that it is not allowing you to configure it for FILE is correct behavior.

You should not be trying to run the FILE adapter on an Isolated Host, you need to use a In-Process host.